# Lua ffi string encoding error

Tags: python, lua, torch

I'm a quite newer for Lua, I write a `hdF5` file with python and and encode the string with following code:

```
#guess image_name is the string
imgname = np.zeros(len(image_name))
for i in range(len(image_name)):
    imgname[i] = ord(image_name[i])
```

and I load the encoded `imgname` in Lua with ffi.string as follow:

```
image_name = ffi.string(img_name:char():data()
```

but I got the error: `fb15268637bc28e2175502f1a3bec6fb.jpg���7��R�`, I google this error but find on answers, I was with python2.7 and LuaJIT.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You encode your string in an array of doubles? How do you write and read the HDF5?

Comment: This is because your string is not zero-terminated.  For non-zero-terminated strings, the second argument for `ffi.string` should be specified, it should be equal to the length of the string.  The correct length would help `ffi.string` to cut off the garbage from string's end.